# Angular 5 Скорость отрисовки 7 секунд

Tags: angular4, angular5

Столкнулся с проблемой, провел рефакторинг приложения. И После этого приложение при от рисовки списков стало очень сильно тормозить.
До этого, когда все было в одном компоненте работало намного быстрее.

Возможно я не вижу ошибку, может кто ни будь сталкивался с этим?

Применял стратегию OnPush, установил TrackBy, выключал все material элементы в  компоненте Item и оставлял голые  input, убирал все @Output элементы(думал может быть в них проблема). В гугле  все статьи касаются от рисовки изменений, а не изначальной загрузки. 
Если не получится найти решение придется  применять стратегию подгрузки данных при скролинге, но я понимаю когда массив 500 элементов, а у меня 60

Отредактировал проэкт, теперь выглядит вот так:

```
    Admin-List:
        <ng-container
        *ngFor="let item of data; trackBy: trackByFn; let i = index;">
            <ng-container
                    *ngIf="item['list'].fldGroupByListId === choice['ID']">
                <!-------------------------Admin-Item------------------------>
                <app-admin-item[item]="item"></app-admin-item>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>

        Admit-item:
            <tr *ngIf="!ifSorting">
                <td class="admin-column-allert">
                                <span class='fa fa-exclamation-circle span-button-allert'
                                      *ngIf="item['listMBNotes'].fldCommentSend && !item['listMBNotes'].fldRejection"></span>
                </td>
                <td class="admin-column-allert"
                    dnd-draggable
                    [dropZones]="['boxers-zone']"
                    [dragEnabled]="true"
                    [dragData]="{'id': item['list'].ID}">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput disabled
                               value="{{item['list'].Created | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td class="admin-column-allert">
                    <!--<ng-container
                            *ngIf=" item['list'].ID != olditemID">-->
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput disabled
                               value="{{item['list'].Modified | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td class="admin-column-title">
                    <mat-form-field>
                                        <textarea matInput matTextareaAutosize
                                                  (focusout)="uploadChangeTitle(item['list'].ID, item['list'].Title)"
                                                  [(ngModel)]="item['list'].Title"
                                                  matAutosizeMinRows="1"
                                                  matAutosizeMaxRows="99"></textarea>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td class="admin-column-date">
                    <mat-form-field
                            *ngIf="item['listMBNotes'].fldCommentSend && item['listMBNotes'].fldRejection">
                                    <textarea matInput disabled
                                              placeholder="{{MembersBoardInfo[item['listMBNotes'].fldMemberBoardId]}}"
                                              matTextareaAutosize
                                              matAutosizeMinRows="1"
                                              matAutosizeMaxRows="4"></textarea>
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <mat-form-field
                            *ngIf="item['listMBNotes'].fldCommentSend && !item['listMBNotes'].fldRejection">
                                    <textarea matInput disabled matTextareaAutosize
                                              placeholder="{{MembersBoardInfo[item['listMBNotes'].fldMemberBoardId]}}"
                                              value="{{item['listMBNotes'].fldComment}}"
                                              matAutosizeMinRows="1"
                                              matAutosizeMaxRows="99"></textarea>
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <mat-form-field *ngIf="!item['listMBNotes'].fldCommentSend">
                        <input matInput disabled
                               placeholder="{{MembersBoardInfo[item['listMBNotes'].fldMemberBoardId]}}"
                               value="{{item['list'].fldDateToThink | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td class="admin-column-delete">
                    <span [style.display]="(item['listMBNotes'].fldCommentSend && !item['listMBNotes'].fldRejection) ? 'inline-block' : 'none'"
                                      class='fa fa-reply span-button'
                                      (click)="uploadChangeRejection(item['listMBNotes'].ID, true, $event)"></span>
                    <span class='fa fa-trash-o span-button'
                          (click)="uploadChangeType(item['list'].ID, 'Архив', $event)"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Скриншот IE11 консоли:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Был бы рад, если не много по конкретнее, что именно не нравится

Comment: можешь сделать пример на каком-нибудь сервисе вроде https://stackblitz.com чтобы можно было запустить и посмотреть?

Comment: Тоже не понял минусующих. Поставил плюс. А проект, который мы могли бы потестить - здравая идея.

Comment: Сегодня сделаю, приложу к вопросу.